# How to manage synchronization between two Akka Actors?

Tags: scala, akka

I have two functions to execute. First `calculate()` and then `calculateSomethingElse()`. My problem is to call the first one and wait before the end.

My first idea was to use Await.result like this

```scala
implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
val future = ask(specificActor, Something(id))
Await.result(future, timeout.duration)

implicit val timeout = Timeout(10 seconds)
val future = ask(specificActor, SomethingElse(id))
Await.result(future, timeout.duration)
```

But finally, I don't really need a timeout. Just wait before the end of the fist called.

```scala
class HandlerActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case m1 =>

specificActor ! Something(id)
specificActor ! SomethingElse(id)
  }
}

class SpecificActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    Case Something(id) =>
      myServ.calculate() // return  Future[List[EitherErr[Message]]]
    Case SomethingElse(id) =>
      myServ.calculateSomethingElse() // returns  Future[EitherErr[Unit]]
  }
}
```

Comment: Look like X/Y question (and should read https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/message-delivery-reliability.html )

Comment: Use Future.flatMap, or for-comprehension is probably the most common solution to this. Akka dispatcher handles Future thread scheduling pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it like:

```
for {
  r1 <- ask(specificActor, Something(id))
  r2 <- ask(specificActor, SomethingElse(id))
} yield (r1, r2)
```

or a second option:

```
val result = ask(specificActor, Something(id)).flatMap(r1 => {
  ask(specificActor, SomethingElse(id)).map(r2 => (r1, r2))
})
```

In both case calls will be called one by one, and you will get result if you need, but if one of them will fail, second will not called.